# Drawing a polygon with color in OpenGL causes texture colors to change

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I'm working on a simulation program that draws points and other primitives on top of a large 2D rectangle with a texture mapped onto it.

The problem is, when I draw a polygon and specify a color for the vertices using glColor3f, that color appears to effect the colors of the texture and not just the polygon that I drew. So drawing a red polygon appears to "bleed" onto the entire texture and everything appears reddish.

I attempted to fix this by using glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) prior to drawing the polygon and then enabling again. But this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glColor3f` changes the color of everything you draw after it's called, as you're setting OpenGL's color state. This is just how OpenGL works in general. (`glTranslate/Rotate/Scalef`, `glMultMatrix`, `glLoadIdentity`, etc. work in the same way as they change the transformation state using the matrix chosen by the matrix mode state (set with `glMatrixMode`))

In order to "reset" the color back to the default, call `glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);`

Comment: You are a sir. Thanks. it took me forever to figure out that glColor3f would effect everything, let alone that glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) would reset it...